# caching queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm working on an app that requires me to filter through large amount of records. I've been reading about caching `QuerySets` and related stuff and found some good material.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(<initial_filter_to_narrow_down_size>))
```

After this, I wish to put this qs in cache for later use. I want to apply all the other filters without hitting the database. something like

```
cache.set('qs', qs)
```

but what happens when I will do `qs = qs.filter(q_object)` ? Cache will be modified ? I don't want that. I want `qs` to remain constant until I update it. What should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.filter() clones the queryset before applying the filter. Cache will not be affected.

BTW, you might want to check [JohnnyCache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) ... a great app about queryset caching.

Answer (score 0):

What i have understood from your question is that you just need to get the query set from the cache as shown below.

```
your_cached_qs = cache.get('qs')
```

And then, apply what ever filter you want.

```
your_new_qs = your_cached_qs.filter(further_filter)
```

This will not affect the query set in the cache. Hence, your cache will remain un-changed until you again update it by yourself and your desired result will be achieved.